# How to set up Google pay for API version 23?

Tags: android, android-studio, payment, google-pay

I want to set up Google pay API for Android version 23, so far I can set it up but only for API 24 or higher any idea how this the code am using a link.

```
https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/wallet
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the build.graddle file here - https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart/blob/master/app/build.gradle

> /* Google Payment API is not supported in SDK versions lower than 19. This example requires this version due to use of newer constructs like Optional. */

Now to make it work for device having lower API level that 24, set the minSdkVersion appropriately and build the project. Most likely you will get error and a quick-fix that shall prompt you to surround certain methods with requires API Level 24, follow that.

Now these methods won't be available for your app when it runs on devices running lower API level and you must provide fallback code if necessary.

Hope this helps.

1. Set minSdkVersion to 23 in build.graddle
2. Take suitable actions on the errors and warnings that appear in the code.